# Twilio and queues

Tags: asp-classic, twilio

Is there a way with Twilio to:

1. have a customer call in and be placed in a hold queue
2. Twilio would then dial our CSR's telephone numbers sequentially (or all at once)
3. Connect whichever CSR answered to the customer

I can get the system to answer the phone, place the caller into a queue, but then dialing the CSR and then connecting the CSR to the caller is where I am stuck.

I can get the system to answer, play a message, and then dial a sequence of CSR numbers, but that is it.

BTW: I am using classic ASP, not that it really matters.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

To make Twilio dial out to your CSR's you're going to need to use the REST API, specifically POSTing to the Calls endpoint.  Check out the [docs for making calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

In order to know if the CSR did not answer and you need to call another, you can use the [StatusCallback parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional).  This lets you specify a URL that Twilio will request when the call ends, letting you know why it ended.  If the CSR does not answer then you can find that out in the StatusCallback request by checking the [Status parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) and start a call to another CSR.

You could also start a bunch of outbound calls to a bunch of CSR's at the same time.  If you do this you would need to track all of the calls (I'd just store each calls CallSid somewhere) and then when the call starts use the `<Gather>` verb to have the CSR indicate they want to accept the customers call.  You would then just hangup on all of the other in-progress outbound calls and `<Dial>` that CSR into the Queue which would connect them to the customer.

Hope that helps.